# Fastest way to flip the sign of a double / float in C

Tags: c, floating-point, double, bit-manipulation, sign

What is the fastest way to flip the sign of a double (or float) in C?

I thought, that accessing the sign bit directly would be the fastest way and found the following:

```
double a = 5.0;
*(__int64*)&a |= 0x8000000000000000;
// a = -5.0

float b = 3.0;
*(int*)&b |= 0x80000000;
// b = -3.0
```

However, the above does not work for negative numbers:

```
double a = -5.0;
*(__int64*)&a |= 0x8000000000000000;
// a = -5.0
```

Comment: That code is completely non-portable. Not only do you invoke various platform-dependant implementations of float, you also make your code depentent on endianess.

Comment: Its also likely to kill performance for a register stored floating point number - it would need to be moved to an integer register, have the operation performed, and then moved back to the FP (x87/SSE) register.

Comment: I'm curious to know what calculation has floating point negation as its performance bottleneck

Comment: @Yann Ramin: GCC optimizes '-a' into 'XORPS %XMM1, %XMM0' (GNU syntax), with XMM1 holding the negation bitmask on x86_64 and uses FCHS on x86_32.

Comment: Your code is also a horrible violation of aliasing rules meaning it *will not do what you want* on modern compilers.

Comment: @David You're right, this certainly isn't the bottleneck of my calculation. I'm just trying to squeeze the last bit of performance out of a 5 day Monte-Carlo integration. The 6D unbound integration domain [-∞,∞]^6 is transformed onto [0,1]^6. To calculate the integrand once then requires 63 sign flips in the 6D coordinate vector. The Monte Carlo sample number is usually 10^4-10^5 and the integration has to be carried out for 10^6 different parameter sets. So that makes at least 10^11 sign flips in the overall process.

Comment: @hennes I'd be astonished if you would even notice the time taken by the sign flips/

Comment: @David Yeah, you're right. It was just an idea. And I was curious why that bit twiddling I found didn't work for negative numbers. Thx everyone for your help! :)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Any decent compiler will implement this bit manipulation if you just prepend a negation operator, i.e. `-a`. Anyway, you're OR-ing the bit. You should XOR it. This is what the compilers I tested it do anyway (GCC, MSVC, CLang). So just do yourself a favour and write `-a`

EDIT: Be aware that C doesn't enforce any specific floating point format, so any bit manipulations on non-integral C variables will eventually result in errornous behaviour.

---

**EDIT 2 due to a comment**: This is the negation code GCC emits for x86_64

```
.globl neg
    .type   neg, @function
neg:
.LFB4:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movss   %xmm0, -4(%rbp)
    movss   -4(%rbp), %xmm1
    movss   .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
    xorps   %xmm1, %xmm0  /* <----- Sign flip using XOR */
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE4:
    .size   neg, .-neg
```

It should be noted that `xorps` is XOR designed for floatin points, taking care of special conditions. It's a SSE instruction.

Comment: `Any decent compiler will implement this bit manipulation` this is wrong. The compiler *needs* to account for `NaN` values. `-NaN` is still a NaN, but NaN xor sign bit is no longer a NaN. Compilers can't and wont make this optimization.

Comment: Did you look at the actual binary output? I did it for the mentioned compilers and they do it.

Comment: Thanks for posting the disassembly. VC does not xor the sign bit, it uses `fchs`. I'm somewhat shocked that gcc does this... is this with -O2? NaNs not propagating can lead to serious bugs.

Comment: What's the output for `-log(-1.0f)`? `nan` or `2.14748e+09`?

Comment: @Inverse: XORPS is an instruction designed especially for operation on floats, provisioning for NaNs. Also GCC uses FCHS if compiling for 32 bit target. And no, I didn't use any optimizations.

Comment: @inverse: What are you talking about?  In IEEE, NaN is encoded with the exponent portion set to all ones, and any non-zero mantissa (mantissa zero means infinity).  The sign bit is irrelevant.  Quiet or signalling is (in practice) the highest magnitude bit in the mantissa.  Again, not the sign bit.

Comment: @Inverse: GCC does not do it for any `-O` but for `-ffast-math`. See [Negative NaN is not a NaN?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3596622/183120).

Answer (score 34):

`a=-a`

Comment: This would be the most efficient way. Bit manipulations of floats are not portable, never touch floats with bitwise operators. Leave that to the compiler.

Comment: This seriously borders on NAA. The comment does all the work that the answer doesn’t.

Answer (score 5):

This code is undefined since it violates the strict aliasing rule.
[What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)
To do this well defined you will have to rely on the compiler optimizing it for you.

Answer (score 4):

If you want portable way, just multiply by `-1` and let compiler optimise it.

Comment: Is there a difference between a*=-1 and a=-a? I would suspect the first variant to actually carry out the multiplication instead of just flipping the sign bit and hence to be slower.

Comment: @hennes a) Whether there is a difference depends upon the compiler implementation. b) Why would you suspect that the optimizer is inoperative?

Comment: @Jim Yes, seems you're right. Sorry, I was just curious. Guess I should strengthen my trust in modern compilers.

Comment: There is a big difference. Multiplication is considered an arithmetical operation and must follow a specific set of rules, like setting the floating-point exception flags. Negation is not, and can thus be implemented by toggling the sign bit. (For integers, however, they could be considered the same.)

Comment: @Lindydancer: That's what I thought, too. However, I checked it on GCC and Intel's compiler and couldn't find a difference in performance between a=-a, a*=-1 and a*=-1.0. So I guess they are all optimized the same way by the compiler.

Comment: @hennes: It all depends on the target architecture. If there is a FPU instruction than can do everything, the performance will be the same. However, for many microcontrollers without an FPU there will might be a difference.

Comment: @Lindydancer: Agreed. I didn't think of such situations.

Comment: You could have a difference if you have an accessor to your value: `x.get() *= -1.0` or `x.get() = -x.get()`

Comment: @Caduchon `x.get()` is not an lvalue, so your example makes no sense