# Is there a double value which will remain itself despite any computation applied to it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, floating-point

On the Windows XP..7 platforms, for x86 instruction sets, using standard C++ or a Microsoft compiler, is there a value I can assign a double which, when other computations are applied to it, will always result in that same value?

e.g.

```
const double kMagicValue = ???;
double x = kMagicValue;
cout << x * 9.1; // still outputs kMagicValue
```

As I understand it, there is a floating point error condition that once trigged, the remainder of all floating point computations will result in NAN or something similar...

I ask because I have a series of functions that try to compute a double for a given input, and for some inputs, "no answer (NAN)" is a good output (conceptually).

And I want to be able to be lazy, and string together computations that should, if any part results in NAN, result as a whole in NAN (i.e. kMagicValue).

Comment: Doesn't NaN do that already?

Comment: Yeah, NaN has exactly those properties.

Comment: That's essentially my question: does NaN do that, and if so, how to access and test against it?  EDIT: numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN() sounds like what I'm looking for.  But it's a little incomplete - as in, how to test for one, what are the rules around quiet_NaN vs. signaling_NaN, etc..

Comment: However, NaN will have peculiar properties (x == x is false for x = NaN), and you need to give the proper flag to MSVC (/fp:strict) for it to keep the NaN where it could eliminate it (like in `0 * kMagicConstant`, where it could replace the result by `0`)

Comment: @AlexandreC. That's the sort of issues I was vaguely aware of and hoping for more information on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't rely on `NaN` to do the job. It will always compare false to any value, including itself, and you have to make sure that the platform respects IEEE754 semantics to a certain extent (this includes having a NaN in the first place).

See horror stories there: [Negative NaN is not a NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596622/negative-nan-is-not-a-nan)

If you really want this approach, and you are confident enough about IEEE754 support, be sure to compile with [`/fp:precise`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (since you use MSVC) so that the compiler doesn't optimize away stuff like `0 * NaN`. Be aware that this might impact performance.

To get a NaN,

```
std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()
```

To test for NaN

```
inline bool is_NaN(double x) { return !(x == x); }
```

But this approach is probably more trouble than it is worth. I'd rather use exceptions for control flow here.

The right thing to use is `boost::optional<double>`, but it can be a little verbose at some places

*[Also, the Haskell language has first-class support for these kind of control flow, if C++ is not a must-go option, `Maybe` you can give it a try.]*

Comment: Looking at the /fp documentation, it would appear that /fp:precise explicitly disables intrinsics and optimizations that could be false for IEEE special numbers (including X * 0 -> 0).  So it would appear that /fp:precise (the default) is a good choice for VS 2010

Answer (score 3):

Quiet NaN should do just fine. You can get it from `std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()` by including the `<limits>` header. There's also a signaling NaN, but using it will usually result in an exception.

Remember however, that you can't simple use `mydouble == qNaN`, since NaN compares equal to nothing, not even itself. You have to use that property of NaN to test it: `bool isNaN = mydouble != mydouble;`.

Comment: Just as an aside, comparing NaNs is further complicated by the fact that there are many, many possible representations of it, while by contrast every other floating point value has a unique binary representation (and `+0` and `-0` compare equal).

Answer (score 3):

Any floating point operation involving `NaN` results in `NaN` again (to my knowledge). Moreover, NaN compares unequal to itself, and it is unique among IEEE754 floats with this property. So, to test for it:

```
bool is_nan(double x) { return x != x; }
```

If you have C++11 support, you can use `std::isnan(x) != 0` or `std::fpclassify(x) == std::FP_NAN` from `<cmath>` instead [thanks @James Brock].

To make it:

```
double make_nan() {
  assert(std::numeric_limits<double>::has_quiet_NaN);
  return std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
}
```

Comment: @JamesBrock: Grand - I was just looking for that, but didn't find it in the previous standard. A sorely missed feature; great that's finally included!

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a special floating point value named Not-A-Number (NaN). Any expression with NaN involved will return NaN.

```
#include <limits>
numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()
```

Infinity not always remains the same. For example it become NaN if you try to divide on Infinity.