# gfortran error : isnan has no implicit type

Tags: fortran, nan, gfortran

I am using intrinsic [isnan](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.3/gfortran/ISNAN.html) to check `NaN` which may occur in my program under certain situation.

It was perfectly working in my earlier machine, now after I have switched to a new machine, I am finding the following compilation error message:

```
Error: Function 'isnan' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

However, the code gets compiled with Intel Fortran (ifort) compiler.

The version of the gfortran in the present machine is the following:

```
GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55)
```

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a reasonably up to date compiler you could write

```
 USE, INTRINSIC :: IEEE_ARITHMETIC
```

and then use the function that intrinsic module provides, the one called `IEEE_IS_NAN`.

Answer (score 2):

`isnan` is a non-standard extension and 4.1 is **very** old. Perhaps it was added later. Just upgrade or use `if (x/=x)`

Comment: Thanks. Will `if imag(z) /= imag(z)` work in the same way for a complex `z`?

Comment: If you want to test the imaginary part only, it should (provided imag does not crash, but it shouldn't).

Comment: The check is meant to test the crash ;) . So far no compilation error, I just tested, :)

Comment: Looks like 4.3 when it appeared.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944614/is-it-possible-to-make-isnan-work-in-gfortran-o3-ffast-math?rq=1